# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 48

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, dijkstra

I have an exercise on Dijkstra's Algorithm and when I run my programm I get the following error:
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 48
    What is wrong? I can't sent the entire code because it is 200 lines. But the problem appears in those lines in cmd
    dist[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE; and
    dist[i] = 0;

Thanks in advnace for your help.

```
public static void DijkstraOnNode (int start) {

  int[] dist = new int [myNodes.size()]; //where myNodes is an ArrayList of Hashset<Link>
                                         //and Link is a class that contains node kai weight       
  int[] pred = new int [myNodes.size()];  
  int[] pq = new int [myNodes.size()];

 for (int i = 0; i <= myNodes.size(); i++) {

    if (i!= start)
        dist[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    else
        dist[i] = 0;

   pq[i] = dist[i];
}
```

(the code continues)

Comment: Arrays are 0 base indexed. So it should be `for(int i = 0; i < myNodes.size(); i++) {`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= myNodes.size(); i++)
```

This  causes the problem
 change it to

```
for (int i = 0; i < myNodes.size(); i++)
```

Because, lets say `myNodes.size()` returns 8 and you are trying to reach dist[8] but `dist[]` array starts at 0 and ends at 7.

Comment: Better yet use `dist.length`

Comment: I did so, but when I run the programm again in cmd it returns nothnig. Either it will let me type anything. Like a non stop loop. But perhaps thats a problem in another method.. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @MariaP your method is void and doesn't print out anything.

Comment: Well i have in the method if (printArrays) {
        System.out.println("Predecessor matrix");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pred));
and when i want to run just the algorithm printArrays is initialized as false but when I want to print them I initialize it with true.
Does void not allow it?

Comment: @MariaP it is ok then. You can print in a void method.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays: numbering begins with 0. 
The 9th element, for example, would therefore be accessed at index 8.
So in the loop:

> for (int i = 0; i <= myNodes.size(); i++)

you try to access the element of the array : dist[myNodes.size()] which does not exist. It's Out Of Bounds of the array. 
The last element of the array has index: myNodes.size() - 1

You could see more about arrays here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html